# Grammar question: Which one does "as A as B" part modify?

Tags: expressions

Renewal and reform always depend on a capacity for going backwards to go forward. Key to this process is a search within one’s own mind for a model according to which reformed practice can be organized. Architects have long appealed to a primitive hut as just such a model. It is a structure thought to provide access **as close to the first principles of architecture as it is possible to get**, yet traces of this structure exist nowhere other than in the mind’s eye of the architect searching for it.

I understand the context of the above, but I am not quite sure whether the bold "close" is used as an adjective or an adverb.

If an adverb, the bold part should modify the verb in the clause, "(is thought)" or "provide", if not, the noun, "access." At first, I simply thought "close" is used as an adjective, but soon realized that it does not seem right in grammar, and "close" in the bold part must be an adverb in that sentence. I guess, depending on which one it is, the meaning of the sentence also alters significantly. I would like to know which part of speech "close" is in the sentence above.

Also, I would like to know how I can paraphrase the sentence "Architects have long appealed to a primitive hut as just such a model." I am not sure how I should understand "appeal to" part.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'Close' is being used in the sense of 'near'. The hut is as close as possible to the basic idea of architecture..

Comment: "Close" is an adjective. "As close to the first principles of architecture as it is possible to get" is a preposition phrase with the adjective phrase "close to the first principles of architecture as it is possible to get" functioning as complement to the preposition "as". The whole PP is functioning as complement of "access".